# Java Double Value With Only One Decimal

Tags: java, decimal, bigdecimal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

I am having a Double value like "1234.9678" . i want to return only with one decimal without rounding or ceiling.

I have used this way but its returning "1234.96"

```
public double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {

DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d)); }
```

I want only "1234.9",

I have even used this way... But no luck... Can anyone help?

```
double d = 1234.9678;
int decimalPlace = 1;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( Double.toString(d) );
bd = bd.setScale( decimalPlace, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP );
System.out.println( bd.doubleValue() );
```

Comment: What do you mean "without rounding"? And if you want just one decimal, how about `new DecimalFormat("#.#")`?

Comment: -1, don't think OP put any effort to solve the problem himself.

Comment: wow 0 accept over 13 questions...

Comment: It is returning 1234.0 i mean rounding the value to higher precision, but i want "1234.9" "without rounding" to next higher precision.

Comment: @Thilo Why? Because we want SO to become a better repository of **answered** questions, so it can help others as well? Ok, then I am nuts... ^^

Comment: If you want no rounding, why are you specifying a rounding mode that does rounding? And please don't say things like 'no luck' here. The information is useless. Say what you got and what you expected.

Comment: @brimboriumless-- If possible answer my question rather than commenting..which will be useful to some others when needed as Thilo mentioned..

Comment: @Sandy Your question was already nicely answered by EJP and berry, why should I add another answer with the same content? All you need to do now is to accept one of the answers (the one you think was most helpful to you) and everyone is happy. ;)

Comment: @Sandy Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are two kinds of responses to questions: answers, and comments. The posts you refer to are comments, and they have their own value.

Comment: @Reddy got the answer from berry120 which may be useful for you in future...Make use of it instead of just commenting...

Comment: @brimborium already said what I want to say. You could have find a solution yourself if you put a little effort.

Comment: @Sandy You got the *wrong* answer from berry120, as he has tacitly admitted himself by deleting it. Don't you read the other answers? or just the ones you like?

Answer (score 6):

```
public double roundTwoDecimals(double d)
```

**No method with this signature can possibly do what you ask.** See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12684082/207421) for counter-example.

Floating-point variables don't *have* decimal places, so they cannot be rounded to specific numbers of decimal places. They have *binary* places.

You have to use a decimal radix. In Java this means using either `DecimalFormat` to convert to a String, or `BigDecimal` to convert to a number in decimal radix, round in the decimal radix, then convert that to a String, which is also going to be in decimal radix.

And that implies that you have to change the signature of the method, to either:

```
public BigDecimal roundTwoDecimals(double d)
```

or:

```
public String roundTwoDecimals(double d)
```